# How can I change Network Profiles in Windows 8.1?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, network-profiles

I have a VM running in Hyper-V on my laptop and am having issues managing my networks. I want the VM to have two network connections: Public (bridged w/ the laptop going to the Internet) and Private/Work (a private internal network to share services like SQL Server and other things).

I've setup the virtual switches. The public one works great and, as defaulted, is set to Public to keep most things blocked. However, the one I'm calling the `Intranet` also has its profile set to Public and I cannot figure out how to change it to Work. I thought the way to do this was via Settings -> Change PC Settings -> Network -> click on the network -> some Checkbox/slider. However, when I click on Network, I only see the true public Network connection but it doesn't display my `Intranet` connection. I see both under `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` (and have static IPs set and everything on the Intranet one) but I can't for the life of me figure out how to manipulate the network Profile on the Intranet connection.

Help!!

Comment: You could delete the problem profile in question that should allow you to make the choice again.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not sure what you mean by "delete the problem profile". It is worth mentioning that I was never prompted to select a network profile when it first connected in case you mean deleting and recreating the network/connection.

Comment: The Public/Work settings are just default configuration settings you can manually change those settings if you want.  Normally Windows will ask you what settings you want to apply, there are 3 options, but again the only difference is the default settings that are applied.

Comment: @Ramhound: i know how I can change what "Public" means but I want the two connections to work differently. I want the Public connection to the internet to of course be very firewalled but I want my Intranet connection to be very open.